# CSS Container Min-Height Max-Height declarations

Tags: css, html, height

I have some divs with alternating background-colors that i want to adjust in height depending on the heights of the nested divs within them.
Example is:

```
<div class="tableHolder">
    <div class="oddRow">
        <div class="col1">test1</div>
        <div class="col2">test2</div>
        <div class="col3">test3</div>
        <div class="col4">test4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="evenRow">
        <div class="col1">test1</div>
        <div class="col2">test2</div>
        <div class="col3">test3</div>
        <div class="col4">test4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the CSS declarations would be something along these lines.

```
.oddRow{
    width: 130px;
    min-height: 27px; (this is the default height for all rows unless "col" class grows larger/taller)
    height:auto; (would like it to be able to grow if internal div is taller than 27px)
}
```

.evenRow would be along the same lines for css declarations.  There are also obviously more with the background colors and stuff but i figured that would get the point across.  Any help would be great.
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AL7LB/

Comment: Yea so whats the issue?

Comment: Container height will adjust by default to contain their contents.

Comment: the issue is that the "oddRow" or "evenRow" divs do not grow in height if say "col1" wraps onto a third text row that would make it's height greater than the 27px, oddRow just stays at 27px basically having the background-color cut off and then an extra row of text below it

Comment: Fiddle would be useful.

Comment: @NickG Please post some full HTML/CSS code of what you've tried, that isn't working.

Comment: here is a fiddle of the issue, you can see the text running below the div container.  Sorry about the incomplete thread, http://jsfiddle.net/AL7LB/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are floating your elements. This is why the height doesn't work. You need to apply a clearfix.

```
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

and you need to give the containing element the `clearfix` class, in your case `<div class="tableHolderOdd">`.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AL7LB/1/)

[Some infos about clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Comment: Thank you very much, i was not aware of clearFix, i appreciate your help and quick responses everyone!